# JSF Attributes Ordering plugin

Tags: jsf, coding-style, ide

I;ve inherited some poorly written jsf + richfaces markup looking like this

```
<rich:comboBox selectFirstOnUpdate="true" suggestionValues="#{controller.getSuggestions}"
id="someId" required="true" value="#{entity.value}" converter="#{valueConverter}"
tabindex="42" styleClass="smallCombo">
</rich:comboBox>
```

Question:
Is there any IDE plugin for which I can define an order of JSF(or XML - same in this scope) attributes (for example **id** always goes first, **value** - second, **required** - third)  and then when I format code IDE not only corrects identation and line breaks but also reorders the attributes? 
So as the result my component will look like:

```
<rich:comboBox id="someId" value="#{entity.value}" required="true"
selectFirstOnUpdate="true" suggestionValues="#{controller.getSuggestions}" 
converter="#{valueConverter}" tabindex="42" styleClass="smallCombo">
</rich:comboBox>
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, just press Ctrl + Shift + F.

Comment: @Luiggi: OP want to reorder the attributes (i.e. `id` first and so on), not to format the tag.

Comment: @BalusC oh right, my bad.